# Wrap elements depending on their siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to wrap `p` elements within a single `div` if they come before or after an `.image` class. At the moment, I can only wrap around each individual element.

Here is my CSS:

```
<ul>
    <p>this is the first paragraph</p>
    <p>this is the second paragraph</p>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <p>this is the third paragraph</p>
    <p>this is the fourth paragraph</p>
</ul>
```

and my jQuery:

```
$('p').wrap('<div class="new" />');
$('.image').wrap('<li />');
```

Here is my JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/BDqGe/

Would anyone know how to wrap elements depending on their **siblings**?

Comment: I assume the `ul` element is actually a `div`?

Comment: each element in a ul should be wrapped in an lie should it not ?

Comment: @FelixKling: looks like s/he is adding the `<li>` wrappers after the fact, which makes for some invalid code later corrected by javascript.

Comment: just because they are unordered doesn't mean they are lies :(

Comment: yes adding them after the fact is a bad idea to begin with

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to wrap the `li` elements after. This is for a CMS where the user does not have the ability to wrap elements in a `li`.

Comment: so in your wordpress tinymce or you allow them to make ul's but not li ? I'm pretty sure you can give them the ability to make lists. otherwise you are headed down a slippery slop

Comment: so you want to wrap all the p's in one div? or individual?  Can you show an example of the expected results?

Comment: @Brad: Oh I missed that.

Comment: You cannot fix broken HTML. At the time the JavaScript is executed, the browser already parsed the HTML and corrected in one way or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You HTML is invalid first of all because if you look here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

> > Permitted content for ul - zero or more `<li>` elements, eventually mixed with `<ol>` and `<ul>` elements.

But you can wrap all your elements by using [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) to get all previous siblings and [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to get all siblings after the element - then [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) will wrap them all with a single element

```
$('.image') // start at .image
       .prevAll('p') // <-- get all p's before .image
       .wrapAll('<div class="new" />') // wrap all in a div
       .end() // go back to .image
       .nextAll('p') // get all p's after .image
       .wrapAll('<div class="new" />') // wrap all in div
       .end() // go back to .image
       .wrap('<li />'); // wrap .image in li
```

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jAQQF/)</kbd>

Comment: just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should. My two cents

Comment: @mcgrailm his question is still answerable yeah?no? `Would anyone know how to wrap elements depending on their siblings?`

Comment: yes it is answerable and I think your solution is quite slick. However, should we really encourage people to do things the wrong way ?

Comment: Thanks. Is it wrong because there are no `li` items wrapping the contents? Or because there are multiple `divs` inside the `li` elements?

Comment: @mcgrailm in no way am i encouraging him to do anything wrong - I'm simply answer his question of how to wrap elements depending on their siblings.  I'm not trying to go off topic

Comment: @tmyie it's invalid because inside a `<ul>` element you can only have li elements - so your structure should be `ul > li > your other elements` you can read here about the right way to nest these elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul#Simple_example

Comment: I'm really surprised that this works. Neither Firefox nor Chrome seem to move the `p` and `div` elements outside the `ul` element.

Answer (score 0):

My approach will be

```
var $ul = $('ul');
$ul.find('.image').wrap('<li />');

$ul.children('p').filter(function(){
    var $prev = $(this).prev();
    return $prev.length == 0 || $(this).prev().is(':not(p)')
}).each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil(':not(p)').addBack().wrapAll('<li class="new"/>')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wLDyh/)